# Is it possible to put float numbers for graphs in Achartengine?

Tags: android, floating-point, achartengine

I am using Achartengine for making graphs, and so far it was not so confusing when I made linegraphs with float datas and the achartengine cut the numbers at the decimal point. But if I use PieGraph and count the percentage of all parts and put this number into the graph that indicates the part, it cuts the number at the decimal points again. For example I get three numbers: 28,51,20, summing only 99 :) 
The LineGraph also accepts only integers, so it cuts the 344.6 to 344. 
Is it possible to make float numbers appear on graph using achartengine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this API but it seems that the [model support doubles](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/index.html). So even if they appear rounded for Gfx, values used by the chart engine seem to be doubles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the library accept float variables, but they are converted in double when the float variables are passed to the graph.

I suggest you to use **double** variables because if you want to print the chart values using the function

```
renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
```

if you use float, the function print a lot of decimal numbers